# How to connect phonegap app to database

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Can anyone explain how the phonegap app can be connected database in described manner.

I designed my app by using HTML, CSS and jQuery mobile. Only the problem is how we can access database only using this? I heard we need to use server side code to access database. I don't know any server side code.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want perfectly, but you have to answer the question - where should your database will be situated and how you will manage it. Actually, there are two options - manual installation and cloud service.

First option requires you to add a server side code, because none of major SQL and NoSQL databases expose Http interface directly for managing data. That's why some server side layer should exist. There are libraries for most of DBs that allow you expose REST interfaces to work with, but still you need to integrate them first, even it's usually a simple task.

Second option is to use cloud solutions that already provide that intermediate layer and expose http interfaces as mobile services. (Azure, Amazon, Everlive etc). Here you will need to learn how to manage one before using it.

Comment: Thanks for ur time..can u say which is good and efficient way. And where i can get the steps for that..Thanx in advance..

Comment: It depends on your needs actually. To get steps for the first option google for database rest interface like [Mongo](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/). This is good if you want to learn something about db's and how to work with them. Now second option. If you purpose is to build fast demo app go with [telerik](http://telerik.com) and it's platform month trial, it provides both cordova tools and data services. For the powerful solutions go with Azure or Amazon mobile services.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect via AJAX.

Here the sample code.

```
formData = {
    param1: param1
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://localhost/test.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //success handler
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
```

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/03/18/simple-ajax-data-retrieval/

You can check a sample application using AJAX.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/15/simple-hybrid-mobile-app-using-cordova-and-ratchet-2-complete/

Comment: Is this efficient way?..I heard its not good to use ajax..still In this server side code is needed..what if it is cause problem in future.